# can i passthrough Network Adapter to virtual machine using windows 10 as a host?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

i want to exclusively pass-through network adapter to Open-WRT Virtual-machine i don't want virtual hardware is it possible using windows 10 as a host ?

i tried with virtual-box old version 4.3 pci attach  but i gets eveytime  an  error

thanks in advances

Comment: Why on earth would you want that? If you set the virtual network adapter as bridged, it will become part of your network, which is basically what you are after. No NAT, no opening ports, your virtual machine will register and expose itself in your network as if it was a physical device.

Comment: because i want to have native hardware performance which is giving better performance than virtual driver

Comment: I doubt there is much performance loss. Oracle VirtualBox is really good at this stuff.

Comment: Performance with the virtual network adapter is very good on my machine.

Comment: I just checked now on a Kali VM using the virtual adapter and testing with Speedtest.net and got essentially the same broadband speed as the host machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a hardware adapter for networking without passing through from the host machine, you need a USB Network Adapter (Wired or Wireless) and make the USB device discoverable in the virtual machine.

While this works for some setups, it does not work for all. Then, in this case you would need to stick with the standard Host / Guest hardware setup.

Comment: i tried ethernet usb adapter  but it won't work with OpenWRT , can i use the computer adapter ?

Comment: The host adapter works via the Guest hardware setup. You would need to use that.  I edited my answer to reflect that.